# Ldap search in net-ldap Ruby Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ldap

I am trying to search ldap. This is doing successful authentication, I verified using a correct and incorrect password. Ldap connection is successful. Then when I make a search query it cannot read attributes from LDAP (AD). What is wrong here? Does ldap/AD has any restrictions/permissions on who can what?

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require "net-ldap"
$username = String.new

class ActiveDirectoryUser
  SERVER = '10.10.10.10'
  PORT = 389
  BASE = 'DC=mydomain,DC=com'
  DOMAIN = 'mydomain.com'

  def self.authenticate(login, pass)
    conn = Net::LDAP.new :host => SERVER,
                         :port => PORT,
                         :base => BASE,
                         :auth => { :username => "#{login}@#{DOMAIN}",
                                    :password => pass,
                                    :method => :simple }
    if  conn.bind
        conn.search(
        :base => BASE, :filter => Net::LDAP::Filter.eq(
"sAMAccountName", login ),
        :attributes => %w[ givenName ], :return_result => true) do
|entry|
        puts "givenName: #{entry.givenName}"
        $username = entry.givenName
        end
        return true

    else
      return false
    end
  rescue Net::LDAP::LdapError => e
    return false
  end
end

if ActiveDirectoryUser.authenticate('myusername', 'mypassword')
puts "Authentication Successful! The user is "+$username
#### I get this,but blank username
else
puts "Authentication FAILED!"
end


-----------

# ./ad.rb
Authentication Successful! The user is
```

---

Thanks Terry for the answer. 
It was a small issue. I was missing some details in the treebase. It is working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LDAP-compliant directory servers must provide access control, so it is possible that the LDAP client:

- cannot search for an entry
- cannot read any attributes from an entry
- cannot read some attributes from an entry

It is also possible the entry for which the LDAP client searches does not exist - clients cannot read attributes from entries that do not exist.

The application code should check that the entry in question exists using command-line tools if questions exist as to whether the authentication was successful or whether an entry exists. For information about the command-line `ldapsearch` tool, see [LDAP: using ldapsearch](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/mastering-ldapsearch/).